# how to display all data from .txt to servlet

Tags: servlets

I have a problem on how to display **All** the data from my .txt file to my servlet.

what i have is to display **Only** the last data from my .txt file to servlet

here's the sample code

//index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="add.html" method="POST">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Product name:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="pname" required></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Category:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="cat" required></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Sub:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="subcat" required></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Size:</td>
                                <td><input type="radio" name="size" value="small">Small
                                    <br>
                                <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium">Medium
                                    <br>
                                <input type="radio" name="size" value="large">Large
                                </td>               
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="submit" value="Add"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                    <a href = "view.html">view products</a>
</body>
</html>
```

//AddProductServlet.java

```
package com.nova.ed.process.admin;

import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/add.html")
public class AddProductServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String pname="";
        String cat="";
        String subcat="";
        String size="";

        if(request.getParameter("pname") != null)
        {
            pname = request.getParameter("pname");
        }
        if(request.getParameter("cat") != null)
        {
            cat = request.getParameter("cat");
        }
        if(request.getParameter("subcat") != null)
        {
            subcat = request.getParameter("subcat");
        }
        if(request.getParameter("size") != null)
        {
            size = request.getParameter("size");
        }

        File myFile = new File("product.txt");
        if(!myFile.exists())
        {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        }
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(myFile, true));

        pw.println(pname+","+cat+","+subcat+","+size);
        pw.close();

        out.print("<p>Registration Successfull</p>");
        out.print("click "+"<a href='index.html'>Here</a>"+" to add again");

    }

}
```

//ViewProductServlet.java

```
package com.nova.ed.process.admin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/view.html")
public class ViewProductServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String pname = "";
    public String cat = "";
    public String subcat = "";
    public String size = "";

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        File myFile = new File("product.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));

        boolean isExist = false;

        String str;

        while((str = br.readLine()) != null)
        {

            String [] details = str.split(",");

            pname =  details[0];
            cat = details[1];
            subcat = details[2];
            size = details[3];

            isExist = true;

        }

    if(isExist){

            out.print("<html>");
            out.print("<head>");
            out.print("<title></title>");
            out.print("</head>");
            out.print("<body>");
            out.print("<h3>Products," + pname + " " + cat + " " + subcat + " " + size +"<h3>");
            out.print("<h5>Click <a href='add.html'>here</a> to add more.</h5>");
            out.print("</body>");
            out.print("</html>");

    }else{

    }
    br.close();
    }

}
```

and I'm not using Bean and Beanfactory yet.. but i'll make sure to do it after resolving this problem..

note: still starting please bear with me.. thanks!

btw here's the .txt file I'm talking about:

//product.txt

```
kings of nuts,nuts,premium,small
kings of nuts2,nuts,premium,medium
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your code, the variables you are using to display the results are getting overwrite with the latest values as the while loop progresses and eventually ends up storing only the last row of the file.

You can use Collection variables to store each occurrence of your String output(which corresponds to a row in your text file) which would not lead to overwriting the data on the same variables.